# How to check if two list items contain same content, but in a different order in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I need to check if two lists contain the same items, but in a different order. If the lists have the same item, but in a different order I need to output something specific.  Here's what I've tried and it isn't running at all.

```
def checkguess():
    print('in check guess')
    print(request.json)  # print out the json object to the console
    print(request.json['guess'])  # print out the guess to the console
    print(request.json['enigma'])  # print out the enigma to the console
    guess_list = request.json['guess']
    enigma_list = request.json['enigma']

    hint = {'whitePegs': 0, 'blackPegs': 0}
```

This is the part that isn't working and comes right after the hint:

```
    for x, enigma_item in enumerate(enigma_list):
        if enigma_item != guess_list[x]:
            if guess_list[x] in enigma_item:
                hint['whitePegs'] += 1
```

This is the code that I run if the two lists have the same items in the same order.  This code runs and works.

```
    for x, enigma_item in enumerate(enigma_list):
        if enigma_item == guess_list[x]:
            hint['blackPegs'] += 1
```

Please help!

Comment: would need few more details like - both the lists will always have same number of elements, and the other list should have all same elements but at different indexes ?

Comment: Both lists have 4 elements.  For example, guess_list could be {'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white'} and enigma_list could be {'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'white'}.  There can be no duplicate colors.  I need to output something that shows two of the items in guess_list match two items in engima_list, but they're in the wrong order.

Comment: Use sets instead

Answer (score 0):

```
guess_list = [ 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white' ]
enigma_list = [ 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'white' ]

for x, enigma_item in enumerate(enigma_list):
    if enigma_item != guess_list[x] and enigma_item in guess_list:
        print(enigma_item)
```